# Javac -vresion is empty and how to set that?

Tags: java

I am working on `Amazon ec2` for the first time and verified java version by using the command `java -version` and got the below results:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_201"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

And also run the command `javac -version`, but no results. From this, I have understood the `javac` is not set and none of the java related applications are running. Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What **exactly** does `javac -version` output?   Nothing?  *"Command not found"* or similar?

Comment: `javac` is for Java compiler. Are doing any compilation on EC2? If you are just running Java applications then use `java`. You can check if its present with `java -version`

Comment: I see empty output for javac -version and Yes I am doing the compilation on EC2 and I have verified the java -version and attached output above.

Comment: Check `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`. You may have only installed Java JRE and not the JDK. Also check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html

Answer (score 0):

`javac` should be in the `bin` directory of the java installation dir and `java` in the `jre/bin` directory. You could run `dirname $(readlink -e $(which java))` to find out the absolute path to the `jre/bin` dir and then modify it to the `bin` dir. The result is added to your `PATH` variable in your `~/.profile`.

Add this line to your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`, whichever is read on startup)

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(readlink -e $(dirname $(readlink -e $(which java)))/../../bin)
```

Then logout and login again and test if `javac -version` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

AFTER SETTING YOUR SYSTEM VARIABLE TO JAVA_HOME YOU NEED TO DO THIS FOR IT WORK ON YOUR COMMAND PROMPT:

After setting the JAVA_HOME system variable you need to also set the path so you can use javac from the command prompt:

After setting the JAVA_HOME system variable:

> Inside System Variables find "Path" and click "Edit"
>
> At the end of the Path add this line: ";%JAVA_HOME%\bin" (without the double quotes)
>
> Now click "Ok" and exit out of your command prompt window (If it's still open)
>   now try "javac -version" and it should work
>
> You can also check your java version, JRE build version, and Java Server VM build by typing "java -version"